# What is the reason behind not getting the exact value in python?

Tags: python

int(10000000000000000000000000000000000/10**10)
It should return the exact value like 10000000000000000000000, but the returned value is 999999999999999983222784. What is the reason behind it??

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: In python 3 you have to use `//` to do integer division. Try `int(10000000000000000000000000000000000//10**10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The floating point division operator (`/`) produces an inexact result.  Converting it to an `int` after the fact doesn't fix that.

If you use the integer division operator (`//`) you get an exact integer result:

```
>>> 10000000000000000000000000000000000//10**10
1000000000000000000000000
```